# Compatibility of power packs with different devices

Tags: power-supply, power, amperage

I have 2 different models of the same device. The old model is not receiving power from its power source which is the following power pack:

[image: Old Model's Adapter]

I want to test another power pack to see whether the issue is with the power source but I don't have an identical power pack. This is the power pack that came with the new model of the device:

[image: New Model's Adapter]

Based on the electronics information on these power packs, would the new model's adapter be compatible with the old model device?

Answer (score 1):

The second model of the Power Supply appears to be rated at half the power of the first model as per the specifications (i.e. 60W v/s 30W respectively). I'd say its not adequately rated.

Comment: If I were to connect the second power pack to the device that the first power pack came with, is the worse case scenario that the device just won’t receive sufficient power?

Comment: Yep! That's correct.

Comment: @Speculator surely the worst case is that the power supply overheats, catches fire, and burns the house down.

Comment: @SimonB That’s my question. What happens if you use a power pack that is rated to a lower amperage?

Comment: @GuruJosh If it's well-designed, it will shut down and refuse to work.  If it's cheaply designed, it will overheat and fail.